# Office 2007 look and feel for web site

Tags: html, css

Do you know where a can find a web site template for a web site that would look like Office 2007. I am looking for the right colors, hover, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify and be more specific about what you mean and/or what you're looking for? Office 2007 isn't a website (of course), it's a suite of desktop applications, so without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, it seems as if you're asking how to make an apple "look and feel" like an orange.

Comment: I am looking for a css which has the right gradient colors (light blue, orange when you hover), sizes, fonts, etc, so that the web site looks like Office.

Comment: I'd love to see this site when it's done, please post the URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check something like templatemonster.com, or similar template websites... To be honest, though, you're probably better off using GIMP or Photoshop to re-create the buttons to your liking.

Not sure if this is really applicable, as I didn't look into whether or not this is intended for only platform applications, but microsoft allows you to license office 2007's ui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you mean, but I always though [Extjs](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/) looked sort of like Office. Not exactly, but close. If you want a JS framework, that one might be what you want, or you could skin it.

If you're just looking for a CSS template, I have no idea.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. They have the right colors. I would prefer to avoid java script if possible.